# set_flashdata codeigniter not working when using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to show `set_flasdata` when submitting using AJAX, but `set_flashdata` does not appear.

This my controller:

```
public function updatePassword() {
    $idUser = $this->session->userdata('id_user');
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $data = array();
    $data = $this->user_model->getPassword($idUser, $username);

    $passwordLama = $this->input->post('password-lama');
    $passwordBaru = $this->input->post('password-baru');
    if ($passwordLama == $data['password']) {
        $dataPasswordBaru = array(
            'password' => $passwordBaru
        );
        $this->user_model->updatePassword($idUser, $username, $dataPasswordBaru);
        echo $this->session->set_flashdata('flashSuccess', 'Berhasil mengubah password');
    } else {
        echo $this->session->set_flashdata('flashError', 'Gagal mengubah password');
    }
}
```

This my view:

```
        <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('flashSuccess')): ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success info-alert" id="result-edit-password2">
                <button type="button" class="close" id="close-edit-password2">&times;</button>
                <div id="result-edit-password-text2"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('flashSuccess') ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('flashError')): ?>
            <div class="alert alert-error info-alert" id="result-edit-password2">
                <button type="button" class="close" id="close-edit-password2">&times;</button>
                <div id="result-edit-password-text2"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('flashError') ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
```

this is my AJAX:

```
    $("#form-edit-password").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo base_url('home/updatepassword'); ?>",                        
            data: $(this).serialize(),               
            success: function(html){
                $('.info-alert').show();                    
            }
        });
    });
```

Is there a problem that `set_flashdata` does not appear, please help.

Comment: Flashdata is available only on next server request.. You are using ajax.. So that doesn't work... Reload your page to see that msg

Comment: oh, thanks to your info :)

Comment: @BhuvanRikka : ajax request is a next request, he should get the value

Comment: @user1878292 : what do you mean by  set_flashdata does not appear?, you are just setting it